# jQuery: How to jump to a specific row in a table inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table inside an iframe. I want to jump to a specific row in that table by clicking an element outside the iframe. I've tried to use `hash` to go to an anchor with specified name. It seems to work with only `<a>` element but not `<tr>` as I want. Please take a look the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jump").click(function(){
        top.myiframe.location.hash = "3";
        //top.myiframe.location.hash = "5"; //this works for <a>
    });
});
</script>

<p id="jump">Jump</p>    
<iframe id="myiframe" src="[my iframe url]" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

`myiframe.html` includes:

```
<table>
    <tr name="1"><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr name="2"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr name="3"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr name="4"><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<a name="5">5</a>
```

As you can imagine, I can jump to `<a name="5">5</a>` but not any `<tr>` element. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use hash to a tr element. It works only with anchor tags. Moreoever to select any element from an iframe you have to use the below selector.

E.g to select the tr element inside iframe(myiframe)

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("tr[name=3]");
```

//Code to scroll to the required element in iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jump").click(function(){
        var iframe = $("#myiframe");
        var tr = iframe.contents().find("tr[name=3]");
        $(iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument).scrollTop(tr.offset().top);
    });
});
```

Comment: Then how to jump to a specific `<tr>`?

Comment: What do you mean by jump to? You mean you have to scroll to that tr?

Comment: Yes, but to scroll to that `<tr>` I won't know the specific number of pixel I will scroll to.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli What do you mean by "You cannot use hash to a tr element. It works only with anchor tags."? Are you talking about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/UBQXx/

Comment: @Shaz - The OP has name attribute in tr and not id. Can you make it work with name in your fiddle and also make it run using location.hash?

Comment: @Shaz - Please remove your down vote if you cannot prove me wrong.

Comment: @Protocole - Did you try my answer?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I did not down-vote you. Anyway, that would of been my suggestion in an answer; to use `id`'s instead of `name`'s.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Your answer could work for me if `var iframe = $("#myiframe")[0];`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Protocole - ALWAYS have unique IDs and preferrably starting with a letter or underscore

Answer (score 3):

Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jump").click(function(){
        var row = $("#myiframe").contents().find("tr[name=3]"); // Shankar's code
        row.scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

UPDATE: First make the above script find a row object

Without jQuery it works just fine

document.getElementsByName("row3")[0].scrollIntoView();

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HWB6t/

Comment: @mplungjan Is this required additional plugin download?

Comment: @Shankar - you did, did you not see the comment?

Comment: @Protocole - built-in function

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `id` attribute, rather than the `name` attribute for the `<tr>` elements.

```
<table>
    <tr id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr id="2"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr id="3"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr id="4"><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<a id="5">5</a>
```

[Hash Tag Links That Don’t Headbutt The Browser Window](http://css-tricks.com/7862-hash-tag-links-padding/)